# Laravel 5.1 Update form can't get it to work

Tags: forms, laravel

I keep getting an : `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:` error whenever i try to update an user. I want it to work that an email gets filled in at zoekEmail input. And it will update that row in the database. Can anybody find any flaws in the following code?

Controller function :

```
public function changeMedewerker(){
        $email = Route::current()->getParameter('email');
        return User::updateMedewerker($email);
    }
```

Model function : As you can see here i want to check if the email is the same as the checked input in the view (name=zoekmail)

```
public static function updateMedewerker($email)
    {
        DB::table('gebruikers')
            ->where('email','=', $email)
            ->update(['email' => \Input::get('email')],
                ['username' => \Input::get('gebruikersnaam')],
                ['password' => \Input::get('wachtwoord')],
                ['voornaam' => \Input::get('voornaam')],
                ['achternaam' => \Input::get('achternaam')]);

        return redirect('/medewerkermuteren');

    }
```

Route used :

```
Route::put('changeMedewerker/{email}', array('as' => 'veranderMw', 'uses' =>'UserController@changeMedewerker'));
```

View form :

```
<form method="POST" action="/veranderMedewerker/{{Input::get('zoekmail')}}">
                   {!! csrf_field() !!}
                   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                     <div class="form-group">
                       <div class="input-group">
                         <input type="text" id="zoekmail" name="zoekmail" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail">

                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="email">Email address</label>
                       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="gebruikersnaam">Gebruikersnaam</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gebruikersnaam" name="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="wachtwoord">Wachtwoord</label>
                       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="wachtwoord" name="password" placeholder="wachtwoord">
                     </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="voornaam">Voornaam</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="voornaam" name="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="achternaam">Achternaam</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="achternaam" name="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam">
                     </div>
                             <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-4"><button type="submit" name="veranderGebruiker" class="btn btn-success">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Verander</button>
                            </div>

                           <div class="col-sm-4"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Annuleer</button>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </form>
```

Comment: did you use User namespace in top of your controller?

Comment: i wonder about this, in your form you did specify `...action="/veranderMedewerker/{{Input::get('zoekmail')}}"...` while in your route, you had `Route::put('changeMedewerker/{email}'...` are you sure you didn't miss things here? for safety, you could retrieve route like this `route('veranderMw', $parameter)` where the `$parameter` can be your `{{Input::get('zoekmail')}}` - this approach ensure that laravel throws something back in case the route is not exists (or you configure it the wrong way). also, passing e-mail address through url.. i won't advise this.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't translate it properly my bad. it is now working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed your form's action is pointing to "veranderMedewerker", while your route is named "changeMedewerker" (the english equivalent). The route also points to the wrong controller function "changeMedewerker" instead of "updateMedewerker".

Also, a good practice is to generate url's with the helper function `url('page')`. You could also point to a named route, for instance:

`<form method="POST" action="{{ route('veranderMw') }}">`

You don't need to pass the 'email' URL parameter since you already have that data available from the request. I've revisited your code a little:

```
/**
 * Update the medewerker.
 * 
 * @param Request $request;
 */
public static function updateMedewerker(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');

    User::whereEmail($email)->update($request->all());

    return redirect('/medewerkermuteren');
}
```

And the route:

```
Route::put('updateMedewerker', ['as' => 'veranderMw', 'uses' => 'UserController@updateMedewerker'));
```

This should solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: My code was in dutch and i translated it so english programmers knew what i was trying. guess i did it a bit to fast haha.

Comment: About the above code i got it working but i had to change :  User::whereEmail($email)->update($request->all()); 

to :

User::whereEmail($email)->update($request->except('_token','_method','zoekmail','veranderGebruiker'));

I was wondering do you maybe know a better solution for this? it doesn't look like the best practise =D

and the password don't get hashed so i need to change it a bit haha.

Comment: Yep I noticed, although I prefer coding in english :). Do you get an error using `$request->all()`? Another clean method is to use `$request->only('email', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')`.

Comment: No error just that password didn't got encrypted

Did this instead : $email      = $request->input('zoekmail');

            $data = array(
                'username' => $request['username'],
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),
                'voornaam' => $request['voornaam'],
                'achternaam' => $request['achternaam'],
            );
            User::whereEmail($email)->update($data);
            return redirect('/medewerkermuteren');

Comment: I preffer to code in english aswell i always do but i am on a school assignment and this one has to be dutch unfortunately..

Comment: Okay cool gotcha. But I don't think the Request object can be treated as an array, you might need to use `$request->input('key')` instead of `$request['key']`. Wish I had school assignments with Laravel, much more fun imo :)

Comment: What i have done worked and i think it looks pretty =O